# SliceContourPlot3D works perfectly, but ContourPlot3D returns multiple errors

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting the electric field of a charged ring based a solution from Jackson's *Electrodynamics*.

*Mathematica* handles `VectorPlot3D` and `SliceVectorPlot3D` for the field without a hitch, and `SliceContourPlot3D` of the field magnitude as well.

However, attempting to produce a straight-up `ContourPlot3D` of the field magnitude returns multiple errors, including `Power::infy`,`Infinity::indet`, and `Power::indet`, along with general stop for those errors.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be, and how to work around it to generate a contour plot? This is, by the way, version 10.3.

(I aplogize for the greek letters, they really didn't seem to want to copy cleanly.)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Φ[s_, z_] := Piecewise[{
  {q*Sum[(R^l/(s^2 + z^2)^(0.5*(l + 1)))*LegendreP[l, 1/Sqrt[1 + s^2/z^2]], {l, 0, k}], Sqrt[s^2 + z^2] > R},
  {q*Sum[((s^2 + z^2)^(0.5*l)/R^(l + 1))*LegendreP[l, 1/Sqrt[1 + s^2/z^2]], {l, 0, k}], Sqrt[s^2 + z^2] < R}
 }]

dΦ = -{D[Φ[s, z], s], 0, D[Φ[s, z], z]}; 
dΦc = Simplify[TransformedField["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", dΦ, {s, ϕ, z} -> {x, y, Q}] /. Q -> z]; 

k = 5; q = 5; R = 0.2; 
cont = SliceContourPlot3D[Norm[dΦc], "CenterPlanes", 
          {x, -0.35, 0.35}, {y, -0.35, 0.35}, {z, -0.35, 0.35}, 
          ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 16, 
          ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
Clear[q, k, R]; 

k = 5; q = 5; R = 0.2; 
ContourPlot3D[Norm[dΦc], 
          {x, -0.35, 0.35}, {y, -0.35, 0.35}, {z, -0.35, 0.35}, 
          ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 16, 
          ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x*y*z > 0]]

Clear[k, q, R]
```

Comment: I notice when I try to run your code, simply doing the setup, everything up to and including the `Simplify` part takes a long time.  When answering questions people might often just abort the command if it takes a long time to run and move on to another question (I'm guilty of that sometimes).  If you define the variables `k`, `q`, and `R` ahead of time, then it takes much less time.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, @JasonB. I'll make sure I think about it next time I post something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended comment here, since it doesn't answer the underlying question of *why does this happen*, hopefully someone else may have an answer about why you get those errors. This is a workaround I would use.

For something like this (where the computations seem to take forever and I don't know how long it will take to do the underlying adaptive sampling) I *always* try to use `ListContourPlot3D` instead.  It allows me to see the progress easily, it allows me to decide how long it's going to take.

Check how long a single computation takes,

```
Norm[dΦc] /. {x -> .2, y -> .2, 
   z -> .2} // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0011, 59.3032} *)
```

Now decide how long it will take to get a 3D grid over your range `{-0.35, 0.35}` using a step size of 0.02,

```
36^3 First[%]
(* 52. *)
```

You can use a finer grid if you want to wait more than 52 seconds.

```
data = Table[
    Norm[dΦc] /. {x -> xx, y -> yy, z -> zz}, 
    {xx, -.35, .35, .02}, {yy, -.35, .35, .02}, {zz, -.35, .35, .02}];~Monitor~{xx, yy, zz}
```

(using `Monitor` to check the progress), and then plot it

```
ListContourPlot3D[data, 
 DataRange -> {{-.35, .35}, {-.35, .35}, {-.35, .35}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 16, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x*y*z > 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might get even better results with a finer grid.  Or you can use `ListInterpolation` and get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr1co.png), but it still gives the same errors (just returns a result quicker).

Answer (score 1):

Using your definitions one can determine that the source of the problem is when `x` and `y` are very close to zero.

```
contourList = Partition[
   Flatten[
    Table[{x, y, z, Norm[dΦc]}, {x, -0.35, 0.35, 0.01},
     {y, -0.35, 0.35, 0.01},
     {z, -0.35, 0.35, 0.01}
     ]
    ], 4];
```

Now seek out the elements where the value is `Indeterminate`.

Cases[contourList, {x___, Indeterminate, y___}]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The indeterminate ones are where `x` and `y` are close to zero (i.e., the vertical `z` axis).

This is because there is a pre-multiplier term that has the value

```
dΦc[[1, 3]]
(* 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] *)
```